# Cleaning functions that were not used for a long time

Tags: postgresql

I have a data base with like 10K functions,views,tables...

Is it possible to get information about the last time function/view/table was used?

Does postgresql saves such statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor how often those objects where used, but not *when* they were used the last time.

You need to enable monitoring of the usage, by turning on [`track_io_timing`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-IO-TIMING) and [`track_functions`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-FUNCTIONS)

Once that is enabled you can reset the statistics using [`pg_stat_reset()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCS-TABLE)

Then let your application run for a while and check the statistics:

- [`pg_stat_all_tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) will show you how often a table was accessed
- [`pg_stat_user_functions`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-USER-FUNCTIONS-VIEW) will show you the usage of functions

More details in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html